# How should I write these coupled PDE's in FiPy?

Tags: pde, fipy

I'm trying to implement a phase field solidification model of a ternary alloy using FiPy. I have looked at most of the phase field examples provided on FiPy's website and my model is similar to [examples.phase.quaternary](http://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/examples/phase/generated/examples.phase.quaternary.html).

The evolution equation for the concentrations looks like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvM1r.png]

Which should be solved for C_1 and C_2 (C_3 is solvent). The concentration equations are coupled with the phase evolution equation and we have D_i = D_i(phi), h = h(phi).

There are nonlinear dependencies of the variable solved for (C_i) in all three terms which makes me unsure on how to define them in FiPy. The first term (red) is a diffusion term with a nonlinear coefficient and that should be fine, but how should I define the counterdiffusion and the phasetransformation terms?

I tried defining them as diffusion and convection terms with nonlinear coefficients but without success. Therefore I am hoping for some advice on how I can define so that FiPy likes it.

Any help is highly appreciated, thanks!
/Anders

Answer (score 1):

This set of equations can be solved in a coupled manner. The counter diffusion term can be defined as a coupled diffusion term and the phase transformation term can be defined as a convection term. The equations will be,

```
eqn1 = fipy.TransientTerm(var=C_1) == \
       fipy.DiffusionTerm(D_1 - coeff_1 * (D_1 - D_3), var=C_1) \ # coupled
       - fipy.DiffusionTerm(coeff_1 * (D_2 - D_3), var=C_2) \ # coupled
       + fipy.ConvectionTerm(conv_coeff_1, var=C_1)
```

where

```
coeff_1 = D_1 * C_1 / ((D_1 - D_3) * C_1 + (D_2 - D_3) * C_2 + D_3)
conv_coeff_1 = Vm / R * D_1 * h.faceGrad * inner_sum_1.faceValue
```

and `inner_sum_1` is the complicated inner sum in the phase transformation term. The $\nabla h$ part has been taken out of the inner sum. You can either use `(h.grad * inner_sum_1).faceValue` or `h.faceGrad * inner_sum_1.faceValue` or use face values for the variables that constitute `inner_sum_1`. I don't know how much difference it makes. After both the `C_1` and `C_2` equations are defined in a similar manner, then combine them into one equation with

```
eqn = eqn1 & eqn2
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the input, much appreciated!

However, the variable C_3 is declared as a solvent i.e. :

`components = [
 CellVariable(mesh=mesh, name='C1', hasOld=1),
 CellVariable(mesh=mesh, name='C2', hasOld=1),
]
solvent = Variable(value = 1)
for Cj in components:
 solvent -= Cj
solvent.name = 'C3'`

Such as in examples.phase.quaterny, this means there is no evolution equation for C3, i.e. the constraint between the concentrations is being utilized instead: C1 + C2 + C3 = 1.

Can I still write the term for C3 as a DiffusionTerm as specified in your comment?

Comment: In the case that solving for `C3` is redundant, substitute `C3` from the equations so there is no need to define it.

Comment: The answer is amended with the `C_3 = 1 - C_1 - C_2` substitution.

Comment: Thanks for the comments!

A followup question thought, does it make any difference if I define C3 and insert it in the equations or if I just insert it directly? When you use C3.harmonicFaceValue for example?

Comment: `C_3` need not be defined at all anywhere in the script. If you need use it for something (like plotting for example) then define it as `C_3 = 1 - C_1 - C_2`.